# WSUS Feature Update Fails Error 0x80244019

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I applied the hotfix [KB3095113](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095113) to WSUS in Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard to enable feature updates in Windows 10 1511. Updates began showing up. I approved the new version of windows (1607) and it downloaded fine. When I try to update, the client computer sees the update, show the "Preparing to Install Updates" message then the "Downloading Updates" message. Both get to 100% then I get the Error 0x80244019.

I've tried this on several different clients and get the same result. The client computers can still get normal updates such as cumulative updates for 1511. I have tried re-installing WSUS on the server and cleaning it. Someone suggested turning of "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows." but this has no affect.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://moonlightsoft.blogspot.com/2016/08/error-0x80244019-occurred-while.html
(let it translate)
It worked for me! Appearantly the WSUS server has problems when the client needs to download big updates like 1609. After you add the Mime type, it works.

Comment: Worked great! Wish this was more public. For all those that want a simple English explanation, select _content_ in the ISS site and then _Mime Type_ in the window. Enter _.esd_ in name extension then _application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed_ in MIME type. Thanks so much!

Comment: I just rebooted the server and had to do this step again. Is there a way to keep the mime type added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install [KB3159706](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3159706) and perform manual steps listed on that page?

Comment: The KB3159706 Update had already been installed. I went through the steps to change the Web.config file, but the install still fails.